# Org mode insert heading behaving stranglely

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I probably have some broken config but I can't figure out what I set to break this.

If I have an outline like

```
* Heading
** Subheading1
** Subheading2
```

If I hit M-return or C-return when the cursor is at subheading1 I end up with

```
* Heading
** Subheading1
    **
** Subheading2
```

It should be producing a new subheading, but instead produces something indented which is not treated as a sub heading.

Anyone know how I broke my org mode?

Comment: `C-h k C-RET` in an org buffer and check that it's bound to an org mode defun.  Are you using bundled org?  Is the case specific to one file?  Without more info, bisection of your emacs startup file(s) or a minimal test-case is your only hope =)